# Cannot publish vss-extension. "public": true cause the an error

Tags: javascript, json, azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

I finished my VSTS extension and ready to publish it. I followed the steps here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/publish/command-line.

I receive the following error:

```
i:\Documents\GIT\wdc-extension>tfx extension publish --share-with wdc-extension
TFS Cross Platform Command Line Interface v0.4.11
Copyright Microsoft Corporation
> Personal access token:
Checking if this extension is already published
It is, update the extension
error: Failed Request: Bad Request(400) - Uploaded extension package is either missing an 
icon or the provided icon image does not comply with the required dimensions. 
Try again with a square icon with size 128 by 128 pixels or larger.
```

I noticed that if I remove `"public": true,` from my "vss-extension.json" file, then everything will work fine and the extension will be loaded and it works. The only issue is that it never get published. According to MS, I'm an authorized publisher.

Can anyone can review the below "vss-extension.json" file and check whether I'm missing something. Thanks.

```
{
"manifestVersion": 1,
"id": "wdc-extension",
"version": "1.0.1",
"name": "Weighted Defect Count Calculation",
"description": "Calculate Weighted Defect Count for bugs in the project. Requires a customized scrum process with 2 new attributes: GrundfosScrum.gfLikelihood, and GrundfosScrum.gfSeverity",
"publisher": "wolfguru",
"icons": {
    "default": "images/logo_circle.png"
},
"public": true,
"targets": [
    {
        "id": "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services"
    }
],
"content": {
    "details": {
        "path": "overview.md"
    }
},
"contributions": [
    {
        "id": "wdc",
        "type": "ms.vss-web.hub",
        "description": "Weighted Defect Count",
        "targets": [
            "ms.vss-work-web.work-hub-group"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "name": "WDC Calculation",
            "order": 99,
            "uri": "index.html"
        }
    }
],
"files": [
    {
        "path": "index.html",
        "addressable": true
    },
    {
        "path": "overview.md",
        "addressable": true
    },
    {
        "path": "sdk/scripts",
        "addressable": true
    },
    {
        "path": "images/logo_circle.png",
        "addressable": true
    }
],
"scopes": [
    "vso.work"
],
"tags": [
    "bugs",
    "project management",
    "risk management",
    "defect management"
],
"screenshots": [
    {
        "path": "screenshots/screen1.png"
    }
]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.

The issue is, as the errror message was suggesting, is due to the icon size. It seems that the icon size must not be larger than 128 x 128 pixles when publishing, but it can be larger if I'm not publishing.

Very strange, but that was the reason. I resized the icon and now the extension is published, though the icon is not shown correctly inside the extension :(. Will find a fix for that :)